# How can non-built-in type instances be immutable in python?

Tags: python, immutability, built-in

If I try to run

```
import numpy as np

type(np.dtype).moo = 7
```

then I get

```
TypeError: cannot set 'moo' attribute of immutable type 'numpy._DTypeMeta'
```

which I can't find an explanation for.

`numpy._DTypeMeta` is a `type` instance, so this should be roughly equivalent to

```
type.__setattr__(numpy._DTypeMeta, "moo", 7)
```

So what is happening in `type.__setattr__` that detects `numpy._DTypeMeta` should be immutable?

I could imagine that immutable built-ins such as `float`, might be stored in a specific place in logical memory, and that `type.__setattr__` could check for that, but numpy isn't built-in.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, and I'm curious to see an answer from someone with a better understanding of the C API.

Here is my quick incomplete (and probably incorrect) take:

- `numpy._DTypeMeta` is defined here https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/a115ed3a3c92d8607c5eaa38a98825ac8a5e1bfc/numpy/core/src/multiarray/dtypemeta.c#L964
- The immutable flag (i.e. `Py_TPFLAGS_IMMUTABLETYPE`) is not explicitly applied, but...
- `PyType.Ready()` automatically applies the `Py_TPFLAGS_IMMUTABLETYPE` - https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.Py_TPFLAGS_IMMUTABLETYPE
- `numpy._DTypeMetadata` type is thus immutable.

Comment: I think I understand now. `type.__setattr__` must check the `tp_flags` slot of the type instance, as documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#tp-slots

Comment: @to7m perhaps a charity upvote? :)